# New Requirement for PCI-DSS 3.2

Tags: pci-dss

What are the other requirements in PCI DSS 3.2 rather than these two :

- Revised Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and early Transport Layer Security (TLS) sunset dates as outlined in the Bulletin on Migrating from SSL and Early TLS.
- Expansion of requirement 8.3 to include use of multi-factor authentication for administrators accessing the cardholder data environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Preparing for PCI DSS 3.2 - Summary of Changes](https://blog.pcisecuritystandards.org/preparing-for-pci-dss-3-2-summary-of-changes), the following changes exist in addition to Multifactor and "early TLS" changes:

- “Designated Entities Supplemental Validation” (DESV) is incorporated as an appendix and *may* be required on a case-by-case basis.
- Service Providers are being singled out for more scrutiny given their broader impact on the attack surface.